# Kotlin Azure Service Bus resources & example code

Tags: android, azure, kotlin, azureservicebus

I've developed an Android Kotlin application that posts messages to MQTT broker and works well but I have a requirement to move the functionality and use Microsofts Azure Service Bus which looks very similar.

Are there any resources or example code that demonstrates how I can/should implement Service Bus functionality into my existing Kotlin app. I'm hoping there's libraries that I can use, there appears to be JAVA library but I'm not an expert at integrating and using JAVA with Kotlin.